# Making a jest test file for mysql database calls

Tags: javascript, mysql, jestjs

I'm very new to testing with Jest. I want to make a test to see if the following function returns user data from the database I have:

```
let dbConnect = require('../config/dbConnect');


let findUserByEmail = (email) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            dbConnect.query("SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE email = ?", email, function (error, results) {
                if (error) reject(error);
                let user = results[0];
                if(user == undefined){
                    resolve()
                }
                resolve(user);
            })
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    })
}
```

How would I go about making mock data to use in testing?

EDIT: Here is dbConnect:

```
let mysql = require('mysql');

let dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({path: '../.env'});

let db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
});

db.connect(function (error) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    else console.log("MYSQL Connected...");
});

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: what's `dbConnect` ?

Comment: My database module. Let me edit that in right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: fixed mistake

```js
const mysql = require('mysql')

const mockQuery = jest.fn()
jest.mock('mysql', () => ({
  createConnection: () => ({ 
    connect: () => undefined,
    query: mockQuery
  }),
  
}))

describe('findUserByEmail', () => {
  it('should resolve with the user when query suceeds', async () => {
    mockQuery.mockImplementationOnce((sql, email, callback) => callback(null, ['TEST USER']));
    expect(await findUserByEmail()).toBe('TEST USER');
  })
});
```

Comment: A lot of this is quite foreign to me. Would it be possible to explain it a bit more? Sorry if i'm asking for much, I just want to understand.

Comment: Basically I'm mocking the mysql module with a factory function which allows me to create custom functions. See https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter
Once I do that I can manipulate the query function to do whatever I want